# Why is point $b$ an adherent point to the interval $(a,b)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

**Explain: Why point $b$ is an adherent point to the interval $(a,b)$.**

My answer:
Consider the point y expressed as $y=b - \frac{b-a}{n}, n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then $y$ belongs to the set $(a,b)$. The distance between $y$ and $b$ is given as:
$$|b-y|=\frac{b-a}{n}$$ 
Hence, to get $\epsilon$-closeness, choose $n=\frac{b-a}{\epsilon}$.

Hence, $b$ is an adherent point of $(a,b)$.

Is my proof correct?

Definition ($\epsilon$-adherent points) Let $X$ be a subset of $R$, let $\epsilon > 0$, and let $x\in R$. We say that $x$ is $\epsilon$-adherent to $X$ iff there exists a $y\in X$ which is $\epsilon$-close to $x$ (i.e., $|x- y|\leq\epsilon$).

Definition (Adherent points)Let $X$ be a subset of $R$,let $x\in R$. We say $x$ is an adherent point of $X$ iff it is $\epsilon$ adherent to X for all $\epsilon>0$

Comment: Or, every punctured ball about $b$ meets $(a,b)$: the punctured $\epsilon$-ball about $b$ is $(b-\epsilon,b)\cup (b,b+\epsilon)$, and this meets $(a,b)$ in $(\max(a,b-\epsilon),b)$

Comment: You don't need a punctured ball, as $b$ doesn't belong to $(a,b)$.

Comment: i'm not familiar with the term punctured ball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $I_{\epsilon} = (b - \epsilon, b + \epsilon)$ centered in $b$ you have that $(a,b) \cap I_{\epsilon} \neq \emptyset$. Because $b = \sup (a,b) $ and there exists $b - \epsilon < x \in (a,b)$ and $x \in I_{\epsilon}$.

Comment: the thing b-1/n can be smaller than a.hence, doesnt belong to (a,b). I wanted to say that for any epsilon, there exist an element that is epsilon close to b in (a,b). Is my current writing correct?

Comment: Have you seen the definition of adherent point in metric space?

Comment: no I have not. we defined adherent points of subsets of R

Comment: Would you mind showing it? It's seen as a limit of a sequence of point in a set?

Comment: Because, this definition here says the same thing. We say b is adherent to the set $X$ when for every given $\epsilon > 0$ we have  $B(b ; \epsilon) \cap X \neq \emptyset$. Where $B(b;\epsilon)$ is an open ball with center $b$ and radius $\epsilon$. In our case $I_{\epsilon} = B(b; \epsilon)$.

Comment: I added the defintions. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19865/discussion-between-aaron-maroja-and-mas).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my asnwer. I think it is correct, but I am happy to discuss any of its details.

Assuming $b > a$ to avoid the interval being empty one has

Proof:
Suppose towards contradiction that $b$ is not adherent to $(a,b)$. Then, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $y \in (a,b)$ one has $|b-y| > \epsilon$. By trichotomy either $\epsilon < b-a$ or $\epsilon \geq b-a$. If $\epsilon < b-a$, then let $y = b-\epsilon$. Thus, $|b-y| = \epsilon$. Contradiction. If $\epsilon \geq b-a$ let $y = (b+a)/2$. Then, $|b-y| = |(b-a)/2| < \epsilon$. Contradiction. Therefore, $b$ must be an adherent point of $(a,b)$.